# Correct Python datetime FMT

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601

what is wrong with my FMT formatting for datetime? My date is formatted as follows:

```
mytime = '2021-12-06T13:52:41.864+0000'
```

I am trying to parse it with

```
FMT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+%Z'
```

and

```
FMT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+0000'
```

To be able to do:

```
datetime.strptime(mytime, FMT)
```

Both my solutions do not work. Any idea?

Comment: Do you get an error, or it just isn't the result you are expecting? Also, how are you importing `datetime` ?

Comment: see also [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `+` and use `z` instead of `Z`.

```
from datetime import datetime

mytime = '2021-12-06T13:52:41.864+0000'
datetime.strptime(mytime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

output:

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 6, 13, 52, 41, 864000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong timezone directive in your FMT, use `%z`, not `+%Z`.

`%z`: UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM.